# Tag for cubeworld questions

Tags: support, specific-tag

With the recent duplicate question concerning a cubeworld, I realize that there are quite a few on cubes and other shapes with similar questions such as what the gravity would be like.  And these should be *more discoverable* by new posters.

Since the questions about how gravity points are pretty much the same for any odd situation, and dealing with nonstandard geography is an issue in itself unrelated to the specific shape, I created a new tag [nonsperical-worlds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonsperical-worlds) and would ask that a moderator **create the alias** [cubeworld](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubeworld) (or should it be [cubeworlds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubeworlds)?) for it.

Indeed, editing tags for these questions I found some tried to combine several other tags to convey this situation, and having a clearly named tag for “nonspherical worlds” helped in a couple questions.

Comment: Nominal tags that aren't singleton references should generally be plural, so since "cubeworld" isn't a single world like "earth" is, I vote for 'cubeworlds".

Comment: The stats for my new tag have been digested by the system at last, so I continued by proposing cubeworlds as a synonym.  [Please vote](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/nonspherical-worlds/synonyms) to ratify it.